# What type signature should a removeUndefined method have?

Tags: typescript

A common task in a JavaScript codebase involves removing undefined values from an object, as exemplified here:

```js
function removeUndefined(myObj: any): any {
  const copyObj = { ...myObj };
  Object.keys(copyObj).forEach((key) => (copyObj[key] === undefined) && delete copyObj[key]);
  return copyObj;
}
```

Considering the following scenario:

```js
interface QueryObject {
  id?: number;
  email?: string | null;
  createdAt?: Date | null;
}

async function runQuery(query: QueryObject) {
  const cleanQuery = removeUndefined(query); // type is 'any'
  await engine.run(cleanQuery);
}
```

In my case, I'm not able to turn on `strictNullChecks`, so as far as I can tell, the only way to stop the `cleanQuery` object from receiving something like `{ id: undefined }` would be making its type equivalent to `{ id: number } | { id: number; email: string | null; } | ...`. Is this really the best course of action?

If so, what type signature for this function would achieve such return type for `cleanQuery`?

Comment: "*Ideally, the type of cleanQuery should be equivalent to { id: number } | { id: number; email: string; } | ...*" how is that different to `QueryObject` where each of the properties is optional already? Even assuming it *did* return that union type that shows all possible permutations, you still need to check if  `cleanQuery` has `id` before you reference it, or if it has `email` before you reference it, etc. Seems like the exact same thing but made more cumbersome.

Comment: The difference is that the interface containing optionals accepts an object such as `{ id: undefined }`, which may bause different behavior at runtime.

Comment: If you enable the `strictNullChecks` compiler option (alternatively `strict`) then it *wouldn't* accept that. That will take out `null` and `undefined` from all other domains, so `let x: number = null` becomes an illegal assignment, while `x: number | null = null` now is, but `x = undefined` is still disallowed. So, I do wonder why you're not going that route. Outside the `strictNullChecks` compiler option there is the [`NonNullable`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) utility type that does the same but on an opt in basis.

Comment: Hm, interesting. I didn't remember that strictNullChecks had such an effect, and it makes sense. Thanks for pointing it out. It's not achievable at the moment in our codebase, but it's good to know it would solve such problem. I'll edit the question to clarify this.

Comment: OK, I was under the impression that the `NonNullable` utility type works without enabling `strictNullChecks`. However, it appears that's not the case. I really don't know why I ever thought that, to be honest. I don't think there is a way to type your function without that. At best you can make it generic, receive `T` and produce [`Partial<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype). After all, you can always produce an object with *less* keys from this. But you cannot ensure that the values would be non-null.

Comment: My solution or other workarounds coulb be type safe only if you will use literal object as an argument, otherwise it is impossible fo TS to figure out which property is null or not. Because such kind of checking can be done only in runtime

Answer (score 3):

I made it for both active and disabled `strictNullChecks` options.
Mostly, because I overlooked :D

`strictNullChecks: true`

```js
type RemoveUndefined<T> = {
   [P in keyof T]: undefined extends T[P] ? never : null extends T[P] ? never : P
}[keyof T]

type Keys<T> = Array<keyof T>

const keys = <T,>(obj: T) => Object.keys(obj) as Keys<T>
const isFalsy = <T,>(elem: T) => elem === undefined || elem === null

const removeUndefined = <T,>(myObj: T) =>
   keys(myObj)
      .reduce((acc, elem) => isFalsy(elem) ? acc : { ...acc, [elem]: myObj[elem] }, {} as Pick<T, RemoveUndefined<T>> )

const result =  removeUndefined({ age: 'hello', name: undefined, surname: null }) // { age: 'hello' }
```

I'm not a fan of next solution:

```js
function removeUndefined(myObj: any): any {
  return Object.keys(myObj).forEach((key) => (myObj[key] == null) && delete myObj[key]);
}
```

This function mutates the object and uses `delete` operator,  this is no-no)
My solutions , does not mutate anything

**UPDATE**

I replaced `FilterTrueValues` with `Pick`

**UPDATE** (I hope this is the final one :D)

I added `IsAny` utility, because I forgot that we should not be in `strictNullChecks` mode. Apologies for that.
Thanks to @VLAZ for pointing this out!

Please keep in mind that if you have `any` type in your interface, you will get in trouble with my solution. I will figure out tomorrow how to deal with [any]

`strictNullChecks: false`

```js
type IsAny<T> = 0 extends (1 & T) ? true : false;

type FilterAny<T> = {
   [P in keyof T]: IsAny<T[P]> extends true ? never : P
}[keyof T]

type RemoveUndefined<T> = {
   [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends undefined ? never : T[P] extends null ? never : P
}[keyof T]

type Keys<T> = Array<keyof T>

const keys = <T,>(obj: T) => Object.keys(obj) as Keys<T>
const isFalsy = <T,>(elem: T) => elem === undefined || elem === null

const removeUndefined = <T,>(myObj: T) =>
   keys(myObj)
      .reduce((acc, elem) => isFalsy(elem) ? acc : { ...acc, [elem]: myObj[elem] }, {} as Pick<T, RemoveUndefined<T> & FilterAny<T>> )

const result = removeUndefined({ age: 'hello', name: undefined, surname: null }) // { age: 'hello' }
```

Comment: You can also use `Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(myObj).filter` instead of `reduce` in newer environments or with a polyfill

Comment: @CertainPerformance sure, but I think `Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(myObj).map` provides more complexity

Comment: But I did not consider nested objects

Comment: With `strictNullChecks=false` this type produces `Pick<T, never>` which just bans all properties regardless of whether they had a value or not. [See demo](https://tsplay.dev/KwX89w)

Comment: @VLAZ good point! Thanks! Honestly, I always work with `strictNullChecks=true`. I don't even know how TS behaves  with disabled `strictNullChecks`. I will edit the answer. SOme how I missed it

Comment: @captain-yossarian yeah, I get that. I often even forget `strict` does not default to `true`. For some reason I thought `NonNullable` worked without `strictNullChecks` because I've almost never use it without.

Comment: @VLAZ same story, I was confused )

Comment: @VLAZ I have fixed

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do it is to use [the `strictNullChecks` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks) which globally removes `null` and `undefined` from the domains of other types. However, if you cannot do it, you're a lot more limited in your options.

You might have to resort to using branded types. See [TypeScript Deep Dive online book](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/nominaltyping). Very simply, branding makes a new type that's *incompatible* with another by using an intersection `&`. So we can make

```
type MyBrand<T> = T & { _myBrand: "any value" };

interface Foo {
    id: number;
}

let obj: Foo = { id: 1 };
let brandedObj: MyBrand<Foo> = { id: 2, _myBrand: "any value" };

brandedObj = obj; // not allowed
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictNullChecks=false&target=7&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBCAnAhgOwCYB4AqA+KAvFNlAGRQDeUA+gLYIoYBcUARGiFAG7IA2ArhFZQAvgG4AsAChpAS1TAIiAGbIAxtABiAe22VpUQ1FnoWqfrQBGSyVJHTpvCMCjbLAKxY69RKiZYAjKK2Ti6WjOgQ6ADyHixwSGhY3vi+xqZQAEwANDT0icxsHNx8gsLiDlLhSVGx7oSuHmJQAPQtUKjaLny82gDuUVDSQA)

So, what we could do is produce our own branded type to signify that a given object *has* values. This will ensure that you can distinguish it from other objects that might have nullable values. Another concern is that we don't want anybody to be able to do `brandedObj.existingValue = null`. So, we can use [a mapped type to do all of this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types):

```
const _hasValues = Symbol("has values");

type HasValues<T> = {
    readonly [P in keyof T]?: T[P];
} & {[_hasValues]: true};
```

This is a mapped branded type where:

- the values are the same type as before.
- the keys are the same as the original object but are all made optional. This is because we can *remove* some keys in the process. If the key is present, it's assumed to have a value that's non-nullish.
- the properties are made `readonly` to avoid mutating them further.
- the brand `_hasValues` is applied to distinguish it from other objects. I used a symbol here for the brand to avoid any potential clashes, but you can also use a plain property `{ _hasValues: true }`.

You can complement that with a function that cleans up an object and applies the brand property. Here is an example of how this can be done either via mutating the input or by avoiding to mutate the input:

```
function inlineRemoveUndefined<T>(myObj: T): HasValues<T> {
    const keys = Object.keys(myObj) as (keyof T)[];

    for (const key of keys) {
        if (myObj[key] == null)
            delete myObj[key];
    }

    const brand = {[_hasValues]: true} as const;
    
    return Object.assign(myObj, brand) as HasValues<T>;
}

function cloneAndremoveUndefined<T>(myObj: T): Partial<HasValues<T>> {
    const existingKeyValuePairs = Object.entries(myObj)
        .filter(([,value]) => value != null);

    const brand = {[_hasValues]: true} as const;

    return Object.assign(Object.fromEntries(existingKeyValuePairs), brand) as Partial<HasValues<T>>;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictNullChecks=false&target=7#code/MYewdgzgLgBA+gCwIYQGpIDYFcCmEYC8MAygJ4C2ARiBgBQBEy+AbprhPQJQDcAsAFACopAA44YACRTpseADwAVAHyEYAbwEwtMAE44kAE3AZSMANoAFGAEswMANY5SIAGYwFAXQD8ALneWPPn4AXxgAMnUzRGk2PA8-KB1cYIEBFywwYChrcBswDFscACUcchBmHABVMAMcF0KDRSVaclIAeUoAKz8FTj8pNFiIJvVNbVBIWEdSfCIOzpwsgDppiBb2rs4YFBhaadd3TjNA1P5tGBcQHV2J6AcnGAPVrY0z8+1rN3X5s2mPQiIYCwGAwnDG73etQwOCg4laPz+QXOKUEby0t1glB0SBqqjUUSYMnY8RgiWS23wGKR2nBuhhWB0dnmiygSxQEGsAHMwN8ugAaGBYnEGLY7AZE+TKIIotIZLI5OzADDgHAAQRqejKFWqtXqYBwjWUvO6hz8FiQOmymDk4qGTRUr3OGJgOAAHtZoLZOQBpJwS83WHSzGDM5Y4MCJax4Y1gtHvJb1DCwnS0WhmPmsWQeLYEFSZ3AwACEgOBoKCtOdQtxRHx0UGsggJLJOFCOypp3OeigDKZXRZbIgHO5tFDrJcOhA5AAohGdFG1m6PdkwD6-bEA0HOAKqyKKTBzZbrNbbQ37dLTkA)

At any rate, in your case the `QueryObject` already has optional keys, so the `HasValues<QueryObject>` is assignable to it:

```
//any implementation
declare function removeUndefined<T>(myObj: T): HasValues<T>;

interface QueryObject {
  id?: number;
  email?: string | null;
  createdAt?: Date | null;
}

async function runQuery(query: QueryObject) {
  const cleanQuery = removeUndefined(query);
  await engine.run(cleanQuery);
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictNullChecks=false&target=7#code/MYewdgzgLgBA+gCwIYQGpIDYFcCmEYC8MAygJ4C2ARiBgBQBEy+AbprhPQJQDcAsAFACopAA44YACRTpseADwAVAHyEYAbwEwtMAE44kAE3AZSMANoAFGAEswMANY5SIAGYwFAXQD8ALneWPPn4AXxgAMnUzRGk2PA8-KB1cYIEBAxxgDCQ9GFBIWBwwAHNbHD8Nfm1dLDA-WlsRLCg-AEVcHVIAeUoAKwyoTkIVCx0QcmsIHDkkMFIlAWCggQB6ZZnTa3IRDBxyQqgkKGtwNIysnJca4CPwXV2QZhwAVTB0l1KDRSVaci7evwUnD8UjQsQgXyW-FsUBwOhcSGA4jasL+fWu6k0NgMvhgYCwVFhQS0uyQ1gwOOgOlsRRgAB9cVgMBgibk9IccAYAIJQHEAEXZdIZTKCKUE-BQpDAwBglylNzsSTAyI6tAAju1SK0Nd00QMMZVcuBoLkdjNlaYiHpyA9nq8cO8wBy1RqeJikAB3UkFYqlAB0itomX0SpdIoEQA)

---

For the record, if you are able to use the `strictNullTypes` compiler option then the `HasValues` type can be simplified a lot:

```
//when using strictNullChecks compiler option

type HasValues<T> = {
   [P in keyof T]?: NonNullable<T[P]>;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/C4TwDgpgBAEghgZwGpwDYFcIIDwBUB8UAvFAN4CwAUFDQNoAKUAlgHZQDWEIA9gGZS4AugH4AXFABy3FhPSpUcAEaoIeBoPwBuKgF8qVXuhYBjYE2nMWqVhABKEALbcAbhACqLACYReNz3nwACgcQAHlFACtxXABKcXhkNEwcAjIqGhpjaQRgDi4EYihwiIhTADpOEARgsMiYqEQoQMq+ARjaQW1KdIzebgAnJqyWHLyQKFbKhHqKagz5pn4a4tpKwWISFjlUGJ75-ahvFWBoEJW1rvm9OZo9qH6IYHR+tjPIhoKElAwsAK7rgxGUzmNjGVDSCAAQS8Dycrg83l8LAg-gIy0i0TiUHocH6ZjQ2C+SV+BEIs3mw1GEAAHkwcqwAOYAaS430wOKY-QKJGKpWAZQgLGA-SYWHREV2N32ZV8qBO-UCgVoABpnMTBPUiIQ1T8oABCTbbGJdfRSh5PF5FSJ8mX9bgOACiQpFYppdLMLGZrOJHK59UaOLxTAJRJ+KXwWl0pqAA)

- by using the [`NonNullable`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) utility type we change the types of all values to exclude `null` and `undefined`.
- no need for `readonly`, as now you cannot assign illegal values anyway.
- the keys are still optional because converting a `{id: 1, email: null}` to a `HasValues` will remove the `email` key. Any properties that are present *must* have a non-nullish value.

In this case, a `HasValues<QueryObject>` is still a subset of `QueryObject` and thus assignable to it.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&ssl=12&ssc=11&pln=12&pc=22#code/C4TwDgpgBAEghgZwGpwDYFcIIDwBUB8UAvFAN4CwAUFDQNoAKUAlgHZQDWEIA9gGZS4AugH4AXFABy3FhPSpUcAEaoIeBoPwBuKgF8qVACYQAxgoBO0Y9ITAoEFgHNWEcRWo0oZ9C3EAKVmDowOIAiphmIADyigBWJsAAlMSE9GbcALZMCKpwLCD4utqUVAD0JbkgzOlgKun2wHDATNKGJubQvN7GTdKeEOncAG4QAKosRrzOBnj4vulRseK4CeLwyGiYOARFVKzAEGa8cMbQYQcLcd1kVDRMBmJQLOjpigdFNP1wTKgPNmasDigAB9HnJUO8oMYLI0IAYAILAB4AERhwNB8iKemKlEQIBYxignXxPTYXhYZwivgAjuEQKFadFLolru4rCwbJCVLkKZUSBYBsMxhMptTaQkIXAAO5fWz2JwsCAAOjJvlMEG5YsxVCAA)

Comment: I don't want to exclude `null` values though, only `undefined`. I may have messed up things by copying a removeUndefined implementation that does remove nulls... I just copied the first example from the other SO question. Urgh... That would mean the NonNullable type is too strict, right?

Comment: @villasv ah, I get it. OK, so you can use [`Exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) in that case. `NonNullable<T> = Exclude<T, null | undefined>`, so if you just want to forbid `null` values, you can do `Exclude<T, null>` which still allows `undefined`. Although I don't really see the point - I'd personally just remove both and make the property optional.

Comment: @villasv ah, I got you backwards - you want to *leave* `null` but exclude `undefined`. That would be `Exclude<T, undefined>`. I'll update my answer later when I have a bit more time.

Answer (score 0):

Your function call will have a Partial type signature.
considering the argument you passed is of type T.

```
removeUndefined(myObj: T): Partial<T>
```

Comment: But this doesn't ensure that the result will have non-nullish values. Just that it may be missing some of the keys of `T`.